# Not defined method

Tags: python

below is my code (all the methods are indented in original), after running that code I get this error:

> NameError: global name 'checkDate' is not defined

the method are defined so i don't know whats the issue here (the code was in Java and work well there I just did the modification for this to work in python)

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 3:
            self._day, self._month, self._year = args
        elif len(args) == 1:
            self._day = args[0]._day
            self._month = args[0]._month
            self._year = args[0]._year
        else:
            raise TypeError("wrong number of arguments to Date constructor")

    # methods
    # checkDate - Check if the date is valid
    def checkDate (self, day, month, year):
        if year > 0 and month > 0 and month < 13 and day > 0 and day < 32:       
            if month == 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12: return True
            if month == 4 or 6 or 9 or 11:
                if day == 31: return False
                return True
            if month == 2:
                if (month % 4 == 0 and (month % 100 != 0 or (month % 100 == 0 and month % 400 == 0))):
                       if day > 28: return False   
                       elif day > 27: return False
        return False        

    # calculateDate - Computes the day number since the beginning of the Christian counting of years.
    def calculateDate (self, day, month, year):
        if month < 3:
            year -= 1
            month = month + 12
        return 365 * year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400 + ((month+1) * 306)/10 + (day - 62);

    # getDay - Return the day
    def getDay(self): return self._day

    # getMonth - Return the month

    def getMonth(self): return self._month

    # getYear - Return the year
    def getYear(self): return self._year

    # setDay - Sets the day (only if date remains valid)
    def setDay(self, dayToSet):
        if checkDate(dayToSet,_month,_year): _day = dayToSet

    # setMonth - Sets the month (only if date remains valid)
    def setMonth (self, monthToSet):
        if checkDate(_day,monthToSet,_year): _month = monthToSet 

    # setYear - sets the year (only if date remains valid)
    def setYear(self, yearToSet):
        if checkDate(_day,_month,yearToSet): _year = yearToSet

def main():
    birthDate = Date(1,1,2000)
    print(birthDate.getDay())
    print(birthDate.getMonth())
    print(birthDate.getYear())
    birthDate.setDay(8)
    birthDate.setMonth(8)
    birthDate.setYear(1987)
    print(birthDate.getDay())
    print(birthDate.getMonth())
    print(birthDate.getYear())


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: The method call should be `self.checkDate(...)`

Comment: Python != Java.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `self.checkDate()` since `checkDate` is a method of your `Date` class.

Additionally, in `setDay()`, `setMonth()` and `setYear()` the variables being assigned to (`_day`, `_month`, and `_year` respectively) need a `self.` before them as well.